# Java FileInputStream error: "No such file or directory"

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I'm writing a java code to go through a .sfo (a combination of SQL and Fortran) file and remove a certain set of characters whenever they show up in the file. I'm using Eclipse on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine, if that makes any difference. The code is doing what I want, removing the blocks of characters and whatnot, but at the end, after it gives me my output, it shows
"Error: No such file or directory." 
I don't know why; the only external file that I am referencing is the aforementioned .sfo. The file exists, and the file path that I specified in the code is correct. I have permissions to read and write to the file.
Here is my code (more or less; a lot of it is repetitive, so I'll cut out some of the unimportant stuff):

The absolute path is

> C:/Users/frencke/p4/frencke_LOHEPCE00294173/pcs/main/lib/gp/file.sfo.

Yes, I have full permissions on the file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StringSplit {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
            // Here I initialized a bunch of ArrayLists; nothing relevant
            ArrayList<String> arr26 = new ArrayList<String>();
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(
                    "C:/Users/.../file.sfo");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                arr.add(strLine);
                String[] temp;
                String delimiter = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+&\\s+";
                temp = strLine.split(delimiter);
                for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
                    arr2.add(temp[i]);
                // Here I did all of the removal of the various blocks of text
                String[] temp27;
                String delimiter27 = "\t9";
                String strLine27 = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < temp26.length; i++)
                    strLine27 = temp26[i];
                temp27 = strLine27.split(delimiter27);
                for (int i = 0; i < temp27.length; i++)
                    System.out.println(temp27[i]);
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Again, the error message I got was:
"Error: No such file or directory." 
If anyone knows why this is happening, I would love to hear it; thanks!

Comment: What is the absolute path of file.sfo?

Comment: Does the file has the read permission ?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear; the "..." was just showing where I cut out a big part of the file path for reading purposes on this website. The absolute path is there in full in the code (it's C:/Users/frencke/p4/frencke_LOHEPCE00294173/pcs/main/lib/gp/file.sfo.) Yes, I have full permissions on the file.

Comment: @ItsanAlias I edit the commented information. Please make edit in OP next time and why `delimiter = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+&\\s+";`?

Comment: on command prompt move to c: directory and there write `dir C:/Users/frencke/p4/frencke_LOHEPCE00294173/pcs/main/lib/gp/file.sfo`  what is the output showing?

Comment: @Smit Yeah I saw, thanks. I used delimiter = "\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+\\s+&\\s+"; because the Fortran part of the code in the .sfo is Fortran77, not Fortran90, so it has things like "[space][space][space][space]&" where it had to continue an operation from one line to the next.

Comment: @ItsanAlias You are closing the `DataInputStream` in your `while` loop. Anyhow you can still use `\\s+` will encounter one or more whitespace.

Comment: @Smit, okay. Where should I be closing my DataInputStream? And I tried it with just one \\s+, which worked alright for the ampersand split, but when I split some of the more common characters out (such as 1 or +), using one \\s+ took out some of the instances of the characters that I wanted to keep.

Comment: @ItsanAlias You can `close` your resources when your are done with your `file` reading. However I cant give you much info on `regex` as I dont know exactly how your string look like and that will be complete seperate question to ask. First you need to solve the riddle your are facing.

Comment: Wait, I think I got it. I changed in.close(); } to } in.close();. Is that what you meant? Because now it appears to be working fine. The regex isn't a problem; I'm just not explaining why it isn't very well.

Comment: @Smit Okay, I will post it as the answer (as soon as the 8 hours it's requiring me to wait to answer my own question have passed) and accept the answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the InputStream at the end of the first iteration of your while loop - this releases any system resources associated with the stream.

When you try to readLine(), the stream has already been released so that's why it says No such file exists.

I think you meant to put the `in.close()` after the loop, that should work.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I changed that and it works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to give file path like this
**"C:\\Users\\...\\file.sfo"**

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "/" character with `File.separator`. Example:

```
String path = "C:/Users/.../file.sfo";
path = path.replaceAll("//",File.separator);
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path);
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to help; I think that Smit has it figured out. Something about where I close my DataInputStream.